# How to ascertain location (co-ords) of a tweet

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, geolocation

I am using jQuery to retrieve and display tweets regarding 2 football teams in json format.
I am currently outputing the text and user ID but I plan to plot these tweets on a google map. But first I need to grab the location of the tweets.  any ideas on how to achieve this.

The basic code so far is below;

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
var team1, team2; 
team1 = '<?php echo $_GET["team1"]; ?>'; 
team2 = '<?php echo $_GET["team2"]; ?>'; 

var url1="http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23"+team1+"&callback=?";
var url2="http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23"+team2+"&callback=?";

$.getJSON(
    url1,function(results){ // get the tweets
    var res1 = results.results[0].text;
    var userID1 = results.results[0].from_user_id;
    $("#last-tweet1").html(res1 + "<p>user id: " + userID1); // get the first tweet in the response and place it inside the div
    });


    $.getJSON(
    url2,function(results){ // get the tweets
    var res2 = results.results[0].text;
    var userID2 = results.results[0].from_user_id;
    $("#last-tweet2").html(res2 + "<p>user id: " + userID2 + "</p>"); // get the first tweet in the response and place it inside the div
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each result object has a `geo` element. Unfortunately the majority of tweets don't have location information attached so you will not find many.

Comment: Hi Abraham - I can get the user id from the json file - would it be possible to get a location from that somehow? (so not necesarily from where the tweet was sent from)

Comment: Actually, if I use a geocoded call to twitter, I can return only results that have a filled out 'location' (eg, manchester).  Now all I need to so is link that to Google maps somehow.